# Code Error Modification

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where i should make code that draw a vertical triangular wave But here is a problem  the function which is drawOnePeriod that calls the function drawwave calls it with a constant number 5 , this number determines the amplitude for the wave **however, if i want to change this number to modify the amplitude , it mess up the pattern** so i was wondering if i can get some help anywhere cause i can't think of a relation.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void drawOnePeriod(int periodLength)
{

int z = 10;
for (int i = 1; i < periodLength; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j <= z; j++)
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }
    z++;
    cout << "*" << endl;

}
for (int i = 1; i <= 3 + periodLength; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= z; j++)
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }
    z--;
    cout << "*" << endl;
}
for (int i = 1; i < periodLength; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= z; j++)
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }
    z++;
    cout << "*" << endl;


}
}
void drawWave(int nPeriods)
{
for (int i = 1; i <= nPeriods; i++)
{
    drawOnePeriod(5);
}
}
int main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;
drawWave(n);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for that didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you included what output you expect.
Here is my interpretation of a *"vertical triangular wave"*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int amplitude = 8;
    int cycles    = 3;
    int delta     = +1;

    int i=1;
    while (cycles --> 0)
    {
        for(; i>=1 && (i<=amplitude) ; i += delta)
        {
            printf("%*s\n", i, "*");
        }
        i += 2*(delta = -delta);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[**IDEOne Link**](https://ideone.com/rNaA3H)

**Output**

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4448KB
*
 *
  *
   *
    *
     *
      *
       *
      *
     *
    *
   *
  *
 *
*
 *
  *
   *
    *
     *
      *
       *
```